# Increment time only for the given timestamps while retaining the dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

[Here is the picture of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmGTT.png)

I want to increment the startTime by 30 minutes without changing the dates.

This is what I tried but it gives me the type mismatch error.

```
UPDATE Meeting
SET starttime = starttime::time + 30
WHERE purpose = 'Staff';
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `interval`

```
UPDATE Meeting
   SET starttime = starttime + interval '30 minutes'
WHERE purpose = 'Staff';
```